# Introducir enlaces a Regiones un mapa de jvectormap

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ya tengo listo el mapa, como puedo agregarle un links a una region en especifica y me direccione a otra pagina? ayuda por favor. Gracias

Este es el codigo que estoy usando:

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css' href='style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jvectormap.Venezuela.js"></script>
<title>Venezuela</title>

</head>

<body>

<table  width="90%" align="center">
<tr> <td align="center">

<div id="world-map" style="width: 70%; height: 600px"></div>

<script>
  
$(function(){
$('#world-map').vectorMap({map:'Venezuela',
 backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
 series: {
 regions: [{
   values: {"c0":"1","c1":"2"},
   scale: ['#d9d4ca', '#b3d1ff'],
   normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'}]},
   
   regionStyle:{
   
  initial:{
    fill:"#f4f3f0",
    stroke:"#666666",
    "stroke-width":1,
    "stroke-opacity":1},
    
  hover:{
    fill:"#faa432",
    "fill-opacity":"1"}}})})

 </script>

</td> </tr> </table>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: revisa esta pregunta porfavor http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43817/cambiar-marcador-de-jvectormap-por-una-imagen/43822#43822